# pick rows from every group in data frame only when condition satisfies

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a data frame consisting of two columns. Assume it is already grouped by the first column. For every group, I need to pick rows from this data frame only once the value in the column 2 is 100. Is there an optimal way to do this?

At the moment, I have written an iterative solution as follows, which basically reads each group into a temporary data frame and picks rows into a final data frame called finaldf, once the value in column2 is 100.

EDIT : Please note that the data in col2 is not in ascending order, so I cannot use a condition such as mydf$col2 > 100. 100 is merely a placeholder which says, from when onwards I should start picking the rows.

```
myfun = function()
{
  col1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
  col2 = c(80,100,75,90,100,75,100,12,14,150)
  mydf = data.frame(col1,col2)
  finaldf = NULL;

  uniquecol1values = unique(col1)
  for(i in 1:length(uniquecol1values))
  {
    tempdf = mydf[which(mydf$col1 == uniquecol1values[i]),]
    print(tempdf)

    startincluding = 0;
    for(j in 1:nrow(tempdf))
    {
      if(tempdf[j,2] == 100)
      {
        startincluding = 1;
      }

      if(startincluding == 1)
      {
        finaldf = rbind(finaldf,tempdf[j,])
      }
    }
  }

  print(finaldf)
}

> mydf
   col1 col2
1     1   80
2     1  100
3     1   75
4     2   90
5     2  100
6     3   75
7     3  100
8     3   12
9     3   14
10    3  150

> finaldf
   col1 col2
2     1  100
3     1   75
5     2  100
7     3  100
8     3   12
9     3   14
10    3  150
```

EDIT : If I apply a condition such as mydf[mydf$col2>=100,], it only gives me rows where the col2 value is greater than equal to 100. This is not the correct output since we want rows like (1, 75) to be included though 75<100, because we have already seen the value 100 for group 1.

```
> mydf[mydf$col2>=100,]
   col1 col2
2     1  100
5     2  100
7     3  100
10    3  150
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bycol <- split(mydf,as.factor(mydf$col1))
newdf <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(bycol)) {
    col <- bycol[[i]][2]
    lcol <- col >= 100
    start <- min(which(lcol == TRUE))
    fin <- nrow(col)
    newdf <- rbind(newdf, bycol[[i]][start:fin,])
}
```

This shows what the OP first asked for, which was:

```
> newdf
   col1 col2
2     1  100
3     1   75
5     2  100
7     3  100
8     3   12
9     3   14
10    3  150
```

A more compact implementation of this algorithm, using ideas from @nico would be:

```
bycol <- split(mydf,as.factor(mydf$col1))
temp <- lapply(bycol, function(x) {
    col <- x[2]
    lcol <- col >= 100
    x[min(which(lcol == TRUE)) :  nrow(col),]
})
newdf <- do.call("rbind", temp)
```

Comment: thank you it works. I have debugged and understood it. Can we remove the line ranges <- list() because it doesn't look like it's being used.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was my development code.  It has been removed.

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily done with `data.table` package without any `for`/`lapply` loops

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, .SD[which(match(col2, 100) == 1):.N], col1]
#    col1 col2
# 1:    1  100
# 2:    1   75
# 3:    2  100
# 4:    3  100
# 5:    3   12
# 6:    3   14
# 7:    3  150
```

**Explanation**:
The idea is simple, we use `match` per group to find the first occurrence of `100` (because `match` function always returns the first occurrence) and then we simply select all the values after the match downwards until the group ends.

Comment: ahahahah, thank you! I thought I had written something odd in my previous comment and I couldn't figure out what it was!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use:

```
# Split the data frame by col1
mydf.split <- split(mydf, mydf$col1)

# Apply to each group of elements (defined by col1)
# a function
res <- lapply(mydf.split, function(x)
  {
  # Find the position of the first element >= 100
  pos=which(x$col2>=100)[[1]]
  # Get all of the elements afterwards
  x[pos:nrow(x),]
  })

# Convert back to a df
res <- do.call("rbind", res)
```

Comment: No, the values in col2 are not in ascending order. It's possible that the value after 100 is less than 100. Sorry, if the snaphot of data posted gives you that feeling. Have edited the question, please check above.

Comment: Works in that case as well. I am just checking for values mathematically greater than 100, no matter the order, unless I misunderstand your question. Would you add an example for which the above does not work?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. Yes it does work. Thank you, sorry for a question which resulted in downvote, but this just never came to my mind :)

Comment: @IAMTubby to be honest, I don't really agree with the downvote, but the important thing is you solved the issue!

Comment: This does not give the output shown by `finaldf` in the question

Comment: @nico, I'm sorry, the case where the above solution has been added to the question as an EDIT, please see above.

Comment: @ScottWilson, yes, I was just typing out an example, have added it as an EDIT above. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @nico, I am not convinced that `pos=which.min(x$col2>=100)` is really the way to go - it just so happens that the first element of 100 or more is in position 2 in each of the 3 entries in mydf.split.  For example, try `col2 = c(80,100,75,90,100,75,90,12,14,150)` and rebuild mydf.  Perhaps `which(mydf.split[[1]]$col2 > 90)[[1]]` would be better?

Comment: @scottwilson guess it depends how you interpret the question. "once the value is 100" to me implies that you need to look for 100. Now, should it be == rather than >=? Possibly, but I wouldn't use 90, since the threshold is 100, not 90...

Comment: Sorry, that > 90 should have been >=100.  If you use the data values `col2 = c(80,100,75,90,100,75,90,12,14,150) ` yours does not give the right answer.  Try  `pos=which(x$col2>=100)[[1]]` and then `x[(pos):nrow(x),]` as the function body.

Comment: @ScottWilson OK, now I see what you meant. Removed original answer and left your edit.

Comment: Great!  I want to refactor my original answer keep the algorithm but use the more sophisticated techniques of your approach, but I wanted to be sure I completely understood your answer first.